# I need 2 box side by side without space between them by HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css

How to divide a box into ? I need a box at left and another box at right without any space between two box .Those 2 should be separated only by a line .two box should be side by side. Using HTML or CSS .

Comment: Do you have any code? What did you try so far? What resources have you read/used?

Answer (score 0):

For the line to act as a separator, you can use border-right, but I recommend using also border-left for the box on the right.
Just use two divs with display: inline properties and each a width: 50%;

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
.div1{
    width:45%;
    height:50%;
    float:left;
    background-color: blueviolet;
    }
    .div2{
        background-color: aquamarine;
    width:45%;
    height:50%;
    float:left;
    }
</style>
<div class="div1"></div>
<div class="div2"></div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Optionally, use a flexbox with a separator `div`.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  height: 3em;
}

.left {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 40%;
}

.separator {
  width: 1px;
  background-color: darkgray;
}

.right {
  background-color: red;
  width: 40%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="separator"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try This:**

```css
.c1, .c2 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
}

.c1 {
  background-color: red;
}

.c2 {
  background-color: blue;
  border-left:1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="c1"></div>
<div class="c2"></div>
```